# Displaying the Initial View Controller as a Form Sheet

Tags: ios, xcode

What is the proper way to display the initial View Controller as a Form Sheet?

Background: My initial screen is a login controller that after logging in presents a map. When the user logs out it presents the login screen as a form sheet, but when the application launches it is in full screen.

Update: I used the following code to get it to work:

    `UIViewController *loginViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginController"];
    loginViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentViewController:loginViewController  animated:NO completion:nil];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show a empty view controller and display your login controller as a form sheet.

```
// In your initial view controller
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = // What ever you instantiate a login controller
    loginViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil]
}
```

Comment: Close The first login view controller should be a UIViewController but I got it to work.